# C array vs pointer : array is considered as a variable, array+0 is considered as a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor

I've made a container class in C++, and I have a constructor from iterators so I can write `MyContainer<double> x(v.begin(), v.end())` where `v` is a `std::vector<double>`. I would like to be able to do the same with a c-array but :

```
double array[3] =  {1., 2. , 3.};
MyContainer<double> x(array, array+3); // Doesn't work : no matching function for call to ‘MyContainer<double>::MyContainer(double [3], double*)’
MyContainer<double> x(array+0, array+3); // Work
```

What is the origin of the problem and how to solve it ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Care to share the signature of your constructor?

Comment: Please show the declaration of the (template?) constructor involved.

Comment: Guess this will be `MyContainer<double>::MyContainer(double*, double*)`

Comment: Fun fact: `+ array` (the unary plus operator) also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't accept references to iterators, take them by value. It's trying to pass a reference to an array; the failing expression needs the array to decay to a pointer.

Presumably you have

```
template< typename Iter >
MyContainer( Iter const &first, Iter const &last );
```

but you need

```
template< typename Iter >
MyContainer( Iter first, Iter last );
```

Iterators need to be lightweight enough to pass by value; all the standard templates do so.

An array cannot be used as an iterator because it cannot be incremented. The storage is fixed. When you use an array in an expression like `arr + 0` or pass it *by value* to a function, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. But that conversion doesn't happen when passing by reference.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `array+0` is a pointer, while `array` itself is not a pointer, it is an array. Your constructor does not have an overload that takes an array and a pointer, hence the compile fails.

The idiomatic way of dealing with the problem of making the beginning and the ending iterators from an array is using the `begin(...)` and `end(...)` functions:

```
MyContainer<double> x(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
```

The overload takes care of figuring out where the end of your array is, freeing you from the need to add array's length to the pointer.

Comment: I used to think that `array` was the same as `&array[0]` and thus a pointer to the first field of the array. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AFriedrich Yes, you are absolutely wrong. Although arrays can certainly be used as pointers that are equal to `&array[0]`, and they also flat out *decay* to pointers when passed to a function, they have properties that pointers are lacking. They have a size that you can obtain through `sizeof`, and they are copied by value when they are included as members of `struct`s. In fact, wrapping an array in a `struct` is the trick that you can use to pass an array by value, instead of passing it by pointers.